# How to match the given pattern in the given String using only Regular expression

Tags: regular-language

I have been trying this for long but I am not able to figure out the feasible solution.All I could think of is that I need to do something after finding "author".Please help me to figure out the solution. Thank you.

Given string :

```
@misc{diaz2006automatic,
title={AUTOMATIC ROCKING DEVICE},
  author={Diaz, Navarro David and Gines, Rodriguez Noe},
 year={2006},
  month=jul # "~12",
  note={EP Patent 1,678,025}
}
```

The pattern I want to search :

Diaz, Navarro David and Gines, Rodriguez Noe

Answer (score 0):

Here you are, this is in Javascript

```js
function myFunction() {
  var string = `@misc{diaz2006automatic,
  title={AUTOMATIC ROCKING DEVICE},
    author={Diaz, Navarro David and Gines, Rodriguez Noe},
   year={2006},
    month=jul # "~12",
    note={EP Patent 1,678,025}
  }`;
  var result = /(?<=author=\{)[a-zA-Z\s\,]+/.exec(string);
  alert(result);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

The regex lookafters **author={** for characters **[a-zA-Z\s\,]**, which appear one or more times.

You can find out more for **lookahead/lookbehind** using Javascript regex on Google.

Hope this helps.